# can't using namespace although dll got referenced

Tags: c#, dll, reference, visual-studio-2017

I build a solution with 2 projects, 1 is MVC web and 1 is Class library, 
both target .NET 4.6.1 
I include the class library to web/reference, but Visual Studio 2017 doesn't allow me to using it. 
How can I fix it? 
[image: can't using namespace which dll got referenced]
[image: here is a public class in my DLL]

Comment: Just because the assembly is called PdfComparer doesn't mean that it contains any public types in a namespace called PdfComparer. We can't tell from the screenshot what's actually *in* that assembly. If that's your own code, I suggest you check the namespace declarations in it - and make sure that it exposes *public* classes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the question with the class and method I need from my DLL

Comment: Thank you - although note that for code, it's generally better to present it as text than as a screenshot. Are you using a project reference for this, or have you added a reference to a specific DLL? If it's the latter, perhaps it's out of date? (If you could provide a [mcve] that would be great.)

Comment: When you think you have a compile error, start a build and show (by copying text, not only a screenshot) the Build Output where the actual compiler errors and warnings are shown.  For example, if the reference is rejected by the compiler because of a .NET version mismatch, the Build Output window will show that first, before the namespace error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's exactly the same problem I've been dealing with for the past months (since version 15.8.X if I remember correctly), but when I **change the configuration to Release** it works. Not really a solution, but it might help for now.

I have tried rebuilding, cleaning, deleting folders manually, but none of these have worked.